# Extract time from date into new column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, type-conversion, time

I have a `varchar` column named `[Dato Time]` which contains values like:

```
2011-05-12 00
2011-05-12 01
2011-05-12 02
```

So, a date and a Hour-specific time.

I would like to split the date and the time up in two columns, a column named `[Dato]` with datatype `date` and a column named `Time` with datatype `time(7)`.

I extracted the date-part with the following substring:

```
UPDATE Dato_Time SET [Dato] = SUBSTRING([Dato Time], 1, 10)
```

This worked without any problem. But when I try to run the same code for the time-part:

```
UPDATE Dato_Time SET [Time] = SUBSTRING([Dato Time], 12, 13)
```

It gives me the following error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is It SQL Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Char 12 and 13 seem to be hours, with SQL Server 2012, you can build a new time using this part and 0 for missing parts:

> TIMEFROMPARTS ( hour, minute, seconds, fractions, precision )

```
Select TIMEFROMPARTS(SUBSTRING([Dato Time], 12, 13), 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

MSDN: [TIMEFROMPARTS (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213398.aspx)

With SQL Server prior to 2012, you can use such queries:

```
Select DATEADD(HOUR, Cast(SUBSTRING(@x, 12, 13) as int), CAST('00:00' as time))
Select Cast(SUBSTRING(@x, 12, 13)+':00' as time)
```

Comment: Thanks @Julien

Select TIMEFROMPARTS(SUBSTRING([Dato Time], 12, 13), 0, 0, 0, 0)

solved the issue for me.

No need for the "old" code, as I'm running 2014. But thanks again.

Comment: @dmh: Please note also that the third parameter of SUBSTRING is a length, not a position. I'm guessing you want to cut 2 characters at the position of 12 for the time column – therefore the SUBSTRING call should be `CAST(SUBSTRING([Dato Time], 12, 2)`.

Comment: @Andriy,

Select TIMEFROMPARTS(SUBSTRING([Dato Time], 12, 13), 0, 0, 0, 0)

Gave me this output: 

00:00:00.0000000
01:00:00.0000000
etc.

Which is fine for me. Although this would have been more than enough:

00:00
01:00

Comment: The output is of type Time. Therefore it looks like 00:00:00.000000. You should store it using this type and avoid varchar such as 00:00.

Comment: @dmh: Yes, 13 instead of 2 works in this case, because the characters you are extracting are the last two characters of the string – any integer value greater than 2 would give you the last two characters. I'm just pointing out a seeming misconception on your side, because it seemed to me you thought the syntax of SUBSTRING was `SUBSTRING(string_value, start_pos, end_pos)`, while in fact it's `SUBSTRING(string_value, start_pos, length)`.

Comment: @Julien, I understand. That's also what I'm doing after your great help :)

Andriy, I found an example here in stachexchange and used it. It works fine, and as long as it's for ad-hoc analysis purpose, it suits me fine.

Comment: UPDATE Dato_Time SET [Time] = SUBSTRING([Dato Time], 12, 13) + ':00' is mentioned as the second option of this answer and is IMO a more simple workaround to make the implicit conversion to time work